# SVG NSTextAttachment text encoding issue

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, svg, nsattributedstring

To be able to use SVG images for an attributed string created fom HTML, I do

```
func createAttributedString(string: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                   NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding]

    let attributedString = (try! NSMutableAttributedString(
                                    data: data!,
                                    options: options as! [String : AnyObject],
                                    documentAttributes: nil))
    var svgImageAttributes: [NSTextAttachment] = []
    var svgImageRanges: [NSRange] = []
    attributedString.enumerateAttribute("NSAttachment", inRange: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length), options: []) { (attribute, range, stop) -> Void in


        if let attribute = attribute as? NSTextAttachment, fileType = attribute.fileType where fileType == "public.svg-image"{
            svgImageAttributes.append(attribute)
            svgImageRanges.append(range)
        }

    }
    let array = Array(zip(svgImageAttributes, svgImageRanges))

    for i in array {
        let (attachment, range) = i
        if let imageData = attachment.fileWrapper?.serializedRepresentation {
            var chapterTextAttachment:ChapterImageTextAttachment!
            if let preferedImageWidth = self.preferedImageWidth{
                chapterTextAttachment = ChapterImageTextAttachment(data: imageData, ofType: attachment.fileType, desiredWidth: preferedImageWidth)

            } else {
                chapterTextAttachment = ChapterImageTextAttachment(data: imageData, ofType: attachment.fileType)
            }
            let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: attributedString.string.substringWithRange(attributedString.string.rangeFromNSRange(range)!), attributes: ["NSAttachment": chapterTextAttachment])
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center
            string.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: range)
            attributedString.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withAttributedString: string)
        }
    }
    return attributedString
}
```

with `ChapterImageTextAttachment`

```
class ChapterImageTextAttachment: NSTextAttachment {
    let width:CGFloat
    var size: CGSize! {
        set{
            self.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,newValue.width, newValue.height)
        }

        get{
            return self.bounds.size
        }
    }


    init(data contentData: NSData?, ofType uti: String?, desiredWidth:CGFloat = 320) {
        self.width = desiredWidth
        super.init(data: contentData, ofType: uti)
        if let contentData = contentData {
            let string = String(data: contentData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            let svgrender = SVGRenderer(string: self.fixSVGString(string))

            let image = svgrender.asImageWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.width,  1000), andScale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
            self.image = image
            self.size = image.size

        }
    }

    override func attachmentBoundsForTextContainer(textContainer: NSTextContainer?, proposedLineFragment lineFrag: CGRect, glyphPosition position: CGPoint, characterIndex charIndex: Int) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(self.bounds, 0, 20)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func fixSVGString(string:String) -> String {
        var result: String?
        if string.hasPrefix("rtfd"){
            let startIndex = string.rangeOfString("<?xml")?.startIndex
            let stopIndex = string.rangeOfString("</svg>")?.endIndex

            result = string.substringWithRange(startIndex! ..< stopIndex!)

        } else {
            result = string
        }
        return result!
    }
}
```

It works, but has one flaw: non-ASCII chars are broken.

[image]

The starnge thing is, that both the HTML and teh SVG are UTF-8 encoded, but in the attachment class I have to intsantiate the SVG-string as ASCII

```
let string = String(data: contentData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
```

otherwise it will be nil.

The `fixSVGString(_:)` removes some rich text information that were added.

How can I enforce UTF-8 encoding for the SVG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the String came back nil, that means it could not convert using the UTF-8 encoding.  The fact that ASCII "worked" may just mean it took the bytes as-is, so any non-ASCII characters are whatever byte value the previous encoding had, and those are getting misinterpreted later on.

So, quite simply, the data you are converting from is not UTF-8, nor is it ASCII.  The fact you are looking for "rtfd" means that the wrapper data is probably in RTF format, which will have their own character set.  The RTF spec might have an \ansi directive (I think Code Page 1252), \mac (Mac OS Roman), or \pc (Code Page 437) to specify the character set of the contents.  The default is \ansi. Something is getting confused in the character sets.

Instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding, try NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding.  Or use CFStringConvertWindowsCodepageToEncoding() with an argument of 437 and see if the resulting encoding works better.

If you didn't have an NSTextAttachment to begin with, I'd create an NSAttributedString from the data (using NSRTFDTextDocumentType as the document type), then see if you can find the NSTextAttachment in there, and get the data that way via the contents property.

But you do have an NSTextAttachment... so perhaps it is as simple as getting the NSTextAttachment's "contents" property rather than the fileWrapper's serializedRepresentation.  Or does that just return a link?

Comment: `rtfd\0\0\0\0\u{03}\0\0\0\u{04}\0\0\0\u{02}\0\0\0..\u{13}\0\0\0__@PreferredName@__\u{17}\0\0\0__@UTF8PreferredName@__\u{01}\0\0\0.ºƒ\0\0\u{17}\0\0\0\u{17}\0\0\0&\0\0\0\u{01}\0\0\0\0\0\0€\u{17}t\0\0“\u{0F}`

Comment: Oh.  That looks like a private data format from NSFileWrapper -- see http://blog.simonrodriguez.fr/articles/06-09-2015_nsfilewrapper_serializedrepresentation.html .  So, parsing it directly may not be the best idea.  What about the fileWrapper's regularFileContents property?  The data you want should be available directly somewhere from the NSTextAttachment or NSFileWrapper somewhere.